# Error 404 while accessing Handler.ashx via url

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I create an API to send data from server to client using ASP.NET.
I am using this guide: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-send-data-from-android-to-sql-server-using-restful-ap/.
When I try to access the Handler.ashx I get ERR_CONNECTION_RESET error and I don't understand the reason.

web.config file:

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <configuration>
      <!-- To customize the asp.net core module uncomment and edit the following section. 
      For more info see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=838655 -->
      <system.webServer>
        <handlers>
          <remove name="aspNetCore" />
          <add name="aspNetCore" path="*.ashx" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
        </handlers>
        <aspNetCore processPath="%LAUNCHER_PATH%" arguments="%LAUNCHER_ARGS%" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="InProcess" />
      </system.webServer>
      <connectionStrings>
        <add name="ConString" connectionString="Data Source=DESKTOP-1QIGJNA;Initial Catalog=tests;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlCliesnt" />
      </connectionStrings>
    </configuration>
```

Handler.ashx:

```cs
    <%@ WebHandler Language="C#" Class="Handler" %>
    
    using System;
    using System.Web;
    using JsonServices;    
    using JsonServices.Web;    
        
    namespace RESTful_API
        
    {    
        public class Handler: JsonHandler    
        {    
            public Handler()     
            {    
                this.service.Name = "RESTful_API";    
                this.service.Description = "JSON API for android appliation";    
                InterfaceConfiguration IConfig = new InterfaceConfiguration("RestAPI", typeof(ISAPI), typeof(SAPI));    
                this.service.Interfaces.Add(IConfig);    
            }  
    
        }    
    }
```

Comment: That guide is not very good (imho quite bad even). It even suggests raw SQL by string concatenation. That's extremely unsafe and possibly prone to SQL injection attacks. You should find a better source. E.g. the Microsoft documentation. And use entity framework.

Comment: Ok, but for general information, how can I access a Handler.aspx from url? Will I need to change web.config?

Comment: Let's back off a bit. Ashx and aspx files are WebForms files. WebForms has been deprecated and support even dropped in the newest .NET. why are you using it?